# Unpack a ruby .gem without 'gem unpack' available?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

At work I am forced to use an old rubygem version. Upgrading is not possible due to IT department being lazy.

Is there a way to unpack a `.gem` file without `gem unpack`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Gem files are just uncompressed tar archives. You can unpack them using the `tar` command:

```
$ ls
fruity-0.2.0.gem

$ tar xf fruity-0.2.0.gem 
$ ls
data.tar.gz  fruity-0.2.0.gem  metadata.gz
```

The file `data.tar.gz` is a gzip compressed tar archive that contains the gem files, you can unpack it using `tar`:

```
$ mkdir gem; cd gem
$ tar xzf ../data.tar.gz
$ ls
fruity.gemspec  Gemfile.lock  LICENSE.txt  README.rdoc  VERSION
Gemfile         lib           Rakefile     spec
```