# Single file from gem missing after bundle install, included when using gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I run into a weird issue I currently cant' explain:
I'm building a gem and push it to a private gem repository. When installing the gem from said repository with `gem install my-gem` everything works as expected.
However when I include this gem in a Gemfile and run `bundle install`, the gem installs, *BUT* one file is missing, and I'm a bit at loss as to what I'm missing to see.

Structure of the gem:

```
my-gem
├── my-gem.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── my-gem.rb   <== this one is simply missing after bundle install
│   ├── my-gem
│   │   ├── stuff_for_my_gem
        ├──  ...
```

Comment: Have you been actually uninstalling the gem before calling bundle install?

Comment: Good point, yes I did that. I even removed the whole .rvm folder including all gems before I verified this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the root cause of the issue was the existence of the `vendor/cache` from bundler, which included a version of the gem with some faulty namings. As the gem version was not bumped while troubleshooting the issue, bundler always used the cached version.

Even though the gem was uninstalled from the system completely, it was still available in the local `vendor/cache`. Upon `bundle install` in that folder, bundler realized it had that gem available and used it from the cache.
That's also why the issue didn't appear with `gem install`, since with that the `vendor/cache` created by bundle gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

[Unpack the gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824794/unpack-a-ruby-gem-without-gem-unpack-available) and verify the file is physically included. If not, you have a problem in the build process.

Comment: Did that, when I dowload the .gem from the repo there are all files in the right place, as expected.